# Smooch is not forwarding any messages to my integrations. What should I do?

Tags: smooch

I have Smooch connected to Facebook, Slack, and my email. When a user leaves message on Facebook, Smooch will forward the messages to Slack and email. I believe it is Smooch not working because when I test and cross-message between Facebook, Slack, and my email, none of the messages goes thru.

I've checked Smooch Status and lists "All systems are functional".
I've tried dis/reconnecting all the integrations.
I'm on the "Labs" and within the 500 conversation limit.

What else can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours, all the messages start reaching their destinations.

Otherwise my other solution was to reconnect all my integrations to a new Smooch account.